# Oracle apex DEV-INT-PROD

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

How to export the application from DEV to INT and INT to PROD automatically, for now I am doing this process manually by exporting and importing the application which is not the best solution to do. Can you please explain me the process of achieving it with an example.
Thank you in advance